# How to add a `Period` to `java.util.Date`?

Tags: java, date

I have a predefined set of classes, which uses `java.util.Date` (which cannot be altered) and the requirement is to add a specific period to a date object.

I came across how this can be done using `java.time.Period` and `java.time.LocalDate`, but could not find anything to do with `java.util.Date`.

```
.....

Date baseDate = sdf.parse("2015-01-01 20:00");
Period twoMonthsAndFiveDays = Period.ofMonths(2).plusDays(5);

//ideal result would be a Date object with value "2015-03-06 20:00"
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `java.util.Date`? That class is legacy and you should stick to using `java.time.*` classes exclusively - only use Date if you need it for integrating with old code. But don't do any calculation with it, convert between a java.time.* class and java.util.Date only.

Comment: Are you saying that you are *getting* a `Date` object from those predefined classes? Or that you need to pass a `Date` object *back* to them? Or both? Or that you need to *modify* one `Date` object that a predefined class refers to to be that specified period of time later?

Answer (score 2):

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm");

    // The given data
    String dateTimeString = "2015-01-01 20:00";
    Period twoMonthsAndFiveDays = Period.ofMonths(2).plusDays(5);

    ZonedDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, formatter)
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    Instant newTime = dateTime.plus(twoMonthsAndFiveDays)
            .toInstant();
    Date oldfashionedDateObject = Date.from(newTime);

    System.out.println(oldfashionedDateObject);
```

I set my time zone to Asia/Colombo, ran this snippet and got:

> Fri Mar 06 20:00:00 IST 2015

If you need to start from a `Date` that comes from your predefined legacy classes:

```
    // The given data
    Date originalDate = getDateFromLegacyApi();
    Period twoMonthsAndFiveDays = Period.ofMonths(2).plusDays(5);

    Instant newTime = originalDate.toInstant()
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .plus(twoMonthsAndFiveDays)
            .toInstant();
    Date oldfashionedDateObject = Date.from(newTime);
```

So the conversions are

```
java.util.Date <--> Instant <--> ZonedDateTime
```

A `ZonedDateTime` knows how to add a `Period`. Do the conversions to and from `Date` only when you need to for interoperability with you legacy classes.

Answer (score 1):

Since you you already know how to use `Period` on a `LocalDate` object, then you only need to worry about how to convert `java.util.Date` to `java.time.LocalDate`

```
// converting java.util.Date to java.time.LocalDate
Date today = new Date(); //<--your date to be converted/transformed
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(today.getTime());
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault());
LocalDate localDate = localDateTime.toLocalDate();
```

Taken from: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2016/10/how-to-convert-javautildate-to-LocalDate-java8.html#ixzz63z8Djytf

Comment: Since the example in the question specified time of day too (20:00 in the example), I don’t think you want to use `LocalDate` for adding the `Period`. This loses the time of day.